# Mapping a view from an App directory to a URLS.py file in the project Directory for Django

Tags: django, view, django-views, mapping, django-urls

On Django using VS as the Editor, I have 2 directories in the root folder. A Project Directory named Hell and an App Directory named Rango. I have already defined the Rango app Directory in the settings file of the project Directory.

I have created a view in the app directory and I am trying  to map this view to a urls.py file in the project Directory. However, I keep getting the error message that No Module named rango when I run the urls.py file. Can anyone help me here?

urls code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rango import views
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('index/', views.index),
]
```

Views Code

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.http import HttpResponse
   def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("Rango says hey there partner!")
```